# Why shouldn't I extend an instance initialized by Struct.new?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

We have a legacy codebase where rubocop reports some of these errors which I never could wrap my head around:

> Don't extend an instance initialized by `Struct.new`.
>   Extending it introduces a superfluous class level and may also introduce
>   weird errors if the file is required multiple times.

What exactly is meant by "a superfluous class level" and what kind of "weird errors" may be introduced?

(Asking because obviously we didn't have any such problems over the last years.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Struct.new` creates an anonymous class that happens to be a subclass of `Struct`:

```
s = Struct.new(:foo)
#=> #<Class:0x00007fdbc21a0270>

s.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:0x00007fdbc21a0270>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

You can assign that anonymous class to a constant in order to name it:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:foo)
#=> Foo

Foo.ancestors
#=> [Foo, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

That's the regular way to create a `Struct` subclass.

Your legacy code on the other hand seems to contain something like this:

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:foo)
end
```

`Struct.new` creates an anonymous class (it's not assigned to a constant) and `Foo` subclasses it, which results in:

```
Foo.ancestors
#=> [Foo, #<Class:0x00007fee94191f38>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Apparently, the anonymous class doesn't serve any purpose.

It's like:

```
class Bar
end

class Foo < Bar   # or Foo = Class.new(Bar)
end

Foo.ancestors
#=> [Foo, Bar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

as opposed to:

```
class Bar
end

class Foo < Class.new(Bar)
end

Foo.ancestors
#=> [Foo, #<Class:0x00007fdb870e7198>, Bar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The anonymous class returned by `Class.new(Bar)` in the latter example  is not assigned to a constant and therefore neither used nor needed.

Comment: Only because essentially nothing is impossible in ruby. One could assign that class to a constant and change the output of the ancestral chain :) [Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/EnragedFrayedLanserver)

Comment: @engineersmnky just override `ancestors` for maximum confusion: `def Foo.ancestors; super.insert(1, *ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a.sample(3)); end` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A superfluous class level is exactly this class entending `Struct.new`.

[Here is the reference](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-extend-struct-new) to a more detailed explanation with a source code.

The [pull request on this cop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/pull/1571#issuecomment-71946214) also contains a valuable example:

```
Person = Struct.new(:first, :last) do
  SEPARATOR = ' '.freeze
  def name
    [first, last].join(SEPARATOR)
  end
end
```

is not equivalent to:

```
class Person < Struct.new(:first, :last)
  SEPARATOR = ' '.freeze
  def name
    [first, last].join(SEPARATOR)
  end
end
```

The former creates `::Person` and `::SEPARATOR`, while the latter creates `::Person` and `::Person::SEPARATOR`.

I believe the constant lookup is mostly referred as “weird errors.”

Comment: You can also call `Person.ancestors` to reveal the extra class. The former code will have `[Person, Struct, ...]` whereas the latter will have `[Person, #<Class:0x00007fdbc3845110>, Struct, ...]`

Comment: The good vs. bad example isn't of much help if there is no explanation why it's good/bad.

Comment: @awendt it's "bad" because it creates a superfluous class. From the documentation for [`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-c-new): _"Subclassing an anonymous struct creates an extra anonymous class that will never be used."_

Comment: @Stefan Aha! Now we're getting somewhere…

Comment: @awendt subclassing from `Struct.new` is like writing `class Foo < Class.new(Bar); end` instead of `class Foo < Bar; end` (or more precisely `Foo = Class.new(Bar)`) – you'll end up with an anonymous class between `Foo` and `Bar` that will never be used.